# LibGDX Animation disappears when application is exited and re-entered

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been having this a problem for a while now and I just can't find a solution on how to fix it.

I have a character animation in my game, which works perfectly fine, except for the fact that, when I exit the app and enter it back without closing it, it simply disappears. By "disappearing", I don't mean it is just invisible, because if it was, the collision detection would still apply, but it doesn't.

I am using a custom animation class which looks like this:

```
public class Animation {
    private Array<TextureRegion> frames;
    private float maxFrameTime;
    private float currentFrameTime;
    private int frameCount;
    private int frame;

public Animation(TextureRegion region, int frameCount, float cycleTime){
    frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    int frameWidth = region.getRegionWidth() / frameCount;
    for(int i=0; i<=frameCount; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(region, i * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, region.getRegionHeight()));
    this.frameCount = frameCount;
    maxFrameTime = cycleTime / frameCount;
    frame = 0;
}

public void update(float dt){
    currentFrameTime +=dt;
    if(currentFrameTime > maxFrameTime) {
        frame++;
        currentFrameTime = 0;
    }
    if(frame >= frameCount)
        frame = 0;

}
public TextureRegion getFrame(){
    return frames.get(frame);
}
```

}

I have heard about a function called "onPause", but I don't know how to access it. Even if I could, what would I write in there to fix my problem? I am not using GDX's "Screen", but a custom made "State" class.

EDIT: Here is my character movement code:

```
 if(isAlive)
        birdAnimation.update(dt);
 if (position.y > 0 && isAlive) {
        velocity.add(0, GRAVITY * dt);
    }
 velocity.scl(dt);
 if(isAlive) {
        position.add(MOVEMENT * dt, velocity.y);
        velocity.scl(1 / dt);
    }
 if (position.y < 0)
        position.y = 0;
 if(position.y >= 1300 - sprite.getHeight())
        position.y = 1300 - sprite.getHeight();
```

Comment: does this happen when running on mobile only? or also when you run it on desktop?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Happens on all devices

Comment: This is just a guess, a very VERY wild guess. Maybe your character goes through the floor and its falling and falling and falling afterwards. The reason for this is when you return back to the game, all the time that passed will be used as deltatime in the next frame. So your character goes through the floor. You can resolve this easily capping your deltatime just before any calculations with it. Something like: if (delta>0.05) delta = 0.05;

Comment: @Lestat I don't think the possibility of the character falling through the ground exists, since I have a condition for him to die if he falls beyond a certain height

Comment: are you sure he is not dying? anyways, try to print to logcat the position of the character so you know whats happening to him after you return to the game

Comment: @Lestat Ok, I'll try to do that and post here the result

Comment: @Lestat Ok, so after I exit the app and enter it again, the character is still moving on the X axis, but his position on the Y axis is "NaN"

Comment: Why is the y producing a NaN. Are you dividing by 0 or something?

Comment: No, why would I do that?

Comment: Show the code where you update character's position.

Comment: @TomGrillGames added it to the post

Comment: I think the scl() method somehow results in y to be NaN. Maybe dt is no longer trustworthy after pause. Debug the calculations and variables you are doing there. velocity.scl(dt); must reach infinity at some point...